# BuildFile Error In Rotativa.aspnetcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, rotativa

While converting a view as pdf in asp.net core 2.1 app with rotative it gives an error

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path1

Below is my Code

```
var rpt = new ViewAsPdf();
            //rptLandscape.Model = Model;
            rpt.PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Landscape;
            rpt.PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A4;
            rpt.ViewName = "Test";
            byte[] arr = await rpt.BuildFile(actionContextAccessor.ActionContext);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "PDFStorage", "File.pdf"), arr);
```

Although it returns webpage as pdf successfully, but I want to store it inside a folder.
What are the possible reasons for this Error? , I have checked all, it does not even contain property by the name name1

Update 1: Error is not in Path.Combine(), the error is in line before it.

```
byte[] arr = await rpt.BuildFile(actionContextAccessor.ActionContext);
```

Comment: That's not a compilation error, that's a *runtime* error. Post the *full* exception including the call stack. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`. Although I suspect that if you debug the code you'll find that `env.WebRootPath` is NULL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please see update 1

Comment: post the *entire* exception and where the error occurs. Don't force people to guess. The exception's call stack will show which method was called with a NULL path. It may be enough to find out what's wrong. Eg if a `LoadReportUsingTemplateFileName()` throws this, it's a good guess that some template property has no value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Version**

You need to call `RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env);` in `Startup.cs` *and* download and deploy another tool to do the actual conversion work. You should probably find a different library.

**Long version**

Without the actual exception and its call stack one can only guess, or check [the source code](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore/blob/156104fee273fbc4a4cf9beb3f471a4828871e60/Rotativa.AspNetCore/AsResultBase.cs#L184) and try to guess what could go wrong.

The source code for BuildFile is :

```
   public async Task<byte[]> BuildFile(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        //if (this.WkhtmlPath == string.Empty)
        //    this.WkhtmlPath = context.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Rotativa");

        this.WkhtmlPath = RotativaConfiguration.RotativaPath;

        var fileContent = await CallTheDriver(context);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SaveOnServerPath) == false)
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(this.SaveOnServerPath, fileContent);
        }

        return fileContent;
    }
```

`WriteAllBytes` can't be the culprit. It *does* set the `WkhtmlPath` property from the `RotativaConfiguration.RotativaPath` setting though. Following the calls inside `CallTheDriver()` shows that this library just calls an executable with some switches to convert the PDF file.

The [actual call](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore/blob/156104fee273fbc4a4cf9beb3f471a4828871e60/Rotativa.AspNetCore/WkhtmlDriver.cs#L18) that executes the exe, traced from `ViewAsPdf.cs` to `WkhtmlDriver.cs` is :

```
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = Path.Combine(wkhtmlPath, wkhtmlExe),
                Arguments = switches,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                WorkingDirectory = wkhtmlPath,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();
```

If `wkhtmlPath` is null, you'll get a null argument exception. All those calls would appear in the exception's call stack.

The solution is to ensure that the `RotativaConfiguration.RotativaPath` property is set correctly. The repo itself [explains that](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore/tree/156104fee273fbc4a4cf9beb3f471a4828871e60#needs-configuration) :

> Basic configuration done in Startup.cs:

```
RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env);
```

> Make sure you have a folder with the wkhtmltopdf.exe file accessible by the process running the web app. By default it searches in a folder named "Rotativa" in the root of the web app. If you need to change that use the optional parameter to the Setup call RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env, "path/relative/to/root")

BTW what that library does, run a separate executable in a *web application* is a very, very bad idea:

1. Scalability is lost. Running a separate executable for each request is *very* expensive and can easily flood a busy server. That's why production servers don't work this way. If the process hangs, the request hands. You can end up with orphaned processes.
2. Second, it requires elevated permissions - the web app's account has to be able to execute arbitrary executables, something it should *not* be allowed to do.

Finally, forget about cross-platform deployment. The executable name is [hard-coded](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore/blob/156104fee273fbc4a4cf9beb3f471a4828871e60/Rotativa.AspNetCore/WkhtmltopdfDriver.cs#L5) to "wkhtmltopdf.exe", even though the https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ site provides versions for all OSs.

BTW the tool itself provides a C library for use in other applications

Comment: WkhtmlPath  property needed to be set , Thanks . But it always took path automatically , don't know what went wrong this time

Answer (score 0):

`Path.Combine` throws an `ArgumentNullException` if one of the input strings is `null`.

`env.WebRootPath` is `null`, make sure it's initialized with a value.

---

[Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs) of `Path.Combine`:

```
public static String Combine(String path1, String path2, String path3) {
    if (path1 == null || path2 == null || path3 == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException((path1 == null) ? "path1" : (path2 == null) ? "path2" : "path3");
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    CheckInvalidPathChars(path1);
    CheckInvalidPathChars(path2);
    CheckInvalidPathChars(path3);

    return CombineNoChecks(CombineNoChecks(path1, path2), path3);
}
```