# View to PDF in .NET 6

Tags: .net, pdf, .net-6.0

I am trying to parse my .NET View (with model) into a PDF in the back-end.
I've looked at a lot of stack overflow posts and nowhere is a real solution, without paying hundreds of dollars yearly. (IronPDF or SyncFusion) i've also tried using Rotativa, but dont seem to get it working
[image]
[image]

Does anybody have a framework that makes this easy without a massive pricing attached?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found 2 more stackoverflow questions that helped me out to solve this question:
[ASP.NET Core 6 Export PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73433552/asp-net-core-6-export-pdf)
[BuildFile Error In Rotativa.aspnetcore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513393/buildfile-error-in-rotativa-aspnetcore)

Make sure that this:

```
IWebHostEnvironment env = app.Environment;
RotativaConfiguration.Setup((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment)env);
```

Is before app.Run() in Program.cs

Comment: Still wonder if anybody else knows other frameworks